# Canonical url is scraped instead of my original url in facebook while sharing my site link

Tags: php, facebook-sharer, canonical-link

Hi i am having an issue with "Sharing my site's url with facebook". I checked the url in facebook debugger , here i am getting the below issue.

Kindly find the images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxWyL.png
http://i.prntscr.com/58a4d03d61dd4d4da8e08d8c7c367ca7.png

I have given all the required open graph info(meta tags) such as "og:title", "og:type","og:image","og:url". But i am getting the above shown error(The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.).

So kindly help me on this.

1. How my original url(//XXXXX.com/tester) getting changed to that unknown "Canonical URL"(//XXXX.online.de/tester)?
2. How can i change this "Canonical Url"(//XXXX.online.de/tester)? Because facebook scraps this url only not my original url(//XXXXX.com/tester).

Comment: this is the link for facebook url debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook scrapes the webpages to index it's metadata information, and make the webpage a rich object, integrating it to the social graph . 
The canonical url is set at your page head tags, usually as :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
```

You need to remove that kind of tags from your head, because Facebook scrapes information from this tags URL if present .
After that, you need to fetch new scrape information using Facebook Open Graph debugger on :https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ .

Taking a look in Scraped URL "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" is great for find this tags, you will need only to CTRL+F the strange URL .

Use that for checking your open graph meta tags, maybe something is including og:type and og:url tags, or other tags .

Tell us if this worked .